# SSIS - Get non matched rows and load into Dimension Table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have two tables.

1) Staging table with multiple columns and Date being one of them.

```
Date
9/1/2018
```

2) A Date Dimension Table which has only one column called as Date

```
Date
1/1/2018
2/1/2018
3/1/2018
4/1/2018
```

I am writing a logic in SSIS, where it checks the staging table with the dimension table and inserts the missing dates in the dimension table.

To do this, I use the following logic.

[image]

The Lookup component has the correct 1 row input from staging table and returns a value of NULL. So, the insertion fails due to constrains.

I do have  re-direct non matched rows to no match output enabled inside the Lookup on screen 1.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: I suggest that you not rely on slow, hard to maintain SSIS transformations and instead simply run a T-SQL query that does it all for you in the database. In fact... your calendar dimension should have all of the dates in it already regardless of data coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the Lookup operation to add as a New Column :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not the problem. The problem is when a date gets past the lookup and is a duplicate.

Run it through an Aggregate [group by] on the date column before inserting into the dimension.

Make sure you are using the correct date. There will be no lookup matches for the records you want to insert (therefore that column is null by default). You shouldn't even add any columns from lookup for this use.